# Creating a context object with values from several related models

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

I can't seem to figure this out. My view takes an argument for `Team.id`, and I want to return a context object with each `User` object with a certain value in `User.profile.team` and the associated date from `Reports`. I feel like I started on the right track, but am missing something. The output of my template contains all the data I'm trying to get, but not in a way that can be displayed logically.

Basically, I'm using models similar to the following:

```
class Reports(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    product = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    apps_activated = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    prem_submitted = models.DecimalField(max_digits=30, decimal_places=2)

class Team(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    leader = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.PROTECT)
```

Extended user profile:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    COORDINATOR = 1
    LEADER = 2
    ADMIN = 3
    ROLE_CHOICES = (
        (COORDINATOR, 'Coordinator'),
        (LEADER, 'Leader'),
        (ADMIN, 'Admin'),
    )
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    team = models.ForeignKey(Team, on_delete=models.PROTECT,null=True)
    role = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(choices=ROLE_CHOICES, null=True, blank=True)
```

The closest I got in my view to return the desired data is with the following:

```
team = 1
team_name = Team.objects.get(id=team)
team_users = User.objects.filter(profile__team=team).all()
team_stats = []

for user in team_users:
    team_stats.append(Reports.objects.filter(user_id=user.id))
```

With a template that looks like:

```
{% block content %}
<h1>{{ team }}</h1>
<ul>
{% for user in team_users %}
    <li><a href="/reports/user/{{ user.id }}">{{ user.first_name }} {{ user.last_name }}</a></li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>

<ul>
{% for stat in team_stats %}
    <li>
    {% for line in stat %}
        {{ line.product }} {{ line.type }} #etc #etc
        {% endfor %}
    </li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>

{% endblock %}
```

I thought I was on to something with `prefetch_related()`, but couldn't figure it out. Ideally, I'd only have to return one context object to my template.

Edit:

If it makes it more clear, this query returns the results I'm attempting to pass to the template:

```
select auth_user.first_name, auth_user.last_name, r.product, r.apps_activated, r.prem_submitted, r.conversion_percentage, r.type
from auth_user
join home_profile
on auth_user.id = home_profile.user_id
join reports_reports as r
on auth_user.id = r.user_id
where home_profile.team_id = 1
```

which returns rows that look like:

```
first_name-last_name-product-apps_activated-prem_submitted-conversion_rate-type    
user_1-user_1_last-product_1-693-139764.00-53.86-type1
user_1-user_1_last-product_2-74-27400.10-0.00-type1
user_1-user_1_last-product_3-102-19782.00-47.00-type2
user_2-user_2_last-product_1-7-2437.70-0.00-type2
user_2-user_2_last-product_2-52-10608.00-42.54-type3
user_2-user_2_last-product_3-260.40-0.00-type3
```

Comment: Hi Andrew. Is it possible to outline what you’re seeing in your second for loop on your template...

Comment: It returns the associated values from `reports` in the same order as the `users` are listed in the first loop. For instance, in my database, `reports` may have a row that looks like: `id - product - apps_activated - prem_submitted - type - user_id`, and each of those is returned between the `<li>` tags in the nested loop for a specific user. I can snip a row from my database and the actual output from my template if that would help?

Comment: So it’s working, but you’d prefer something tidier. Is it possible to roughly outline what you want in your template...?

Comment: Right! I basically want to be able to combine the two results, so I can associate the `reports` with the `user`, if that makes sense? Also, I added a SQL query to the bottom of my post on how I'd ideally want to return the objects. When I run this query, it returns results how I'd want them organized in the template.

Comment: It feels like you want a `select_related()` query - I will try to add some guidance as an answer, but it may need some modification!

Comment: I've also added a method which requires some modification of your existing models (adding a `ManyToManyField` in `Profile`) ... this seems like a highly likely solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Potential Solution 1**:

So, I would do the following. Change `user` in your `Reports` model to link explicitly to `Profile` (which, in turn, links to the user)

```
class Reports(models.Model):
    profile = models.ForeignKey(Profile, null=True, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    product = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    apps_activated = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    prem_submitted = models.DecimalField(max_digits=30, decimal_places=2)
```

It seems likely that you are looking for a are probably looking for something like a [`select_related()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#select-related) query, adding in an extra `ForeignKey` field for the Profile:

```
reports = Reports.objects.select_related('profile')
```

You can check the resulting SQL via `str(reports.query)`, which should result in sth along the lines of what you outlined in your question.

The returned cursor values are then translated into the appropriate ORM model instances, so that when you loop over these `reports`, you access the related tables' values via their own objects. However, these accesses along the pre-selected forward relations will not cause extra db hits:

```
{% for report in reports %}
     {{ report.profile.user.username }}
     {{ report.product }}
     # ...
{% endfor %}
```

Let me know how you get on, and if we can brainstorm a solution more suitable, if this one isn't.

**Potential Solution 2**:

Perhaps another solution, and maybe the simplest of the two, would be to have a ManyToMany relationship in your `Profile` model to `Reports`:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    COORDINATOR = 1
    LEADER = 2
    ADMIN = 3
    ROLE_CHOICES = (
        (COORDINATOR, 'Coordinator'),
        (LEADER, 'Leader'),
        (ADMIN, 'Admin'),
    )
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    team = models.ForeignKey(Team, on_delete=models.PROTECT,null=True)
    role = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(choices=ROLE_CHOICES, null=True, blank=True)
    reports = models.ManyToManyField(Reports, ...)
```

Then you should be able to loop over `users` in the template:

```
{% for user in users %}
    {% for report in user.reports.all %}
        {{ report.product }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response! Will make changes and report back!

Comment: No worries, it's 6am here so will get some sleep but will check in first thing. I have another potential solution that you might be able to user as well - but it may bloat your DB over time.

Comment: Solution 1 works exactly how I need! One further question: I tried adding a `.filter()` to `Reports.objects.select_related('profile')` to filter by the `team_id`. I can show team members by adding `'team': {'name': team_name, 'team_id':team },` to my context object and an `if` statement to the `for` statement in my `template` like `if team_id = report.profile.team_id`, but is there a way to filter that in the `view`?

Comment: What happens if you tried Reports.object.select_related(‘profile’).select_related(‘team’) ?

Comment: I get the following error: `Invalid field name(s) given in select_related: 'team'. Choices are: profile`. Also tried `select_related(__profile_team_id)`

Comment: Oh no wait you have team in your Profile model. It should just be Reports.objects.select_related(‘profile’).filter(team=team) where team is your team object lookup on team Id.

Comment: so if the profile field is team_id, the team id variable is team, it should be filter(team_id=team)? That gives "Cannot resolve keyword 'team_id' into field. Choices are: apps_activated, conversion_percentage, id, prem_submitted, product, profile, profile_id, type"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178721/discussion-between-andrew-and-micheal-j-roberts).

Comment: So with my the team id being passed to the view as team, and team_obj = Team.objects.get(id=team), reports = Reports.objects.select_related('profile').filter(team_id=team_obj.id) gives the same error. Without the .filter(), I can still output the user's team id with report.profile.team_id